# Error code 010010 is reported when the textSearch API is used after the HMS Core Site Kit is integrated

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I've encountered some problems when using Postman to verify nearbySearch of HUAWEI Site Kit. Can anyone help me?

The function of nearbySearch is to search for nearby POIs meeting the requirements. The following are my requests. [image]

The Post method is used and the header is: https://siteapi.cloud.huawei.com/mapApi/v1/siteService/nearbySearch?key=CV7BC1sVBsLAUHByHhfS9DYd8E5K%2FFlQZ4al3ANV4wKa%2BdQgtDPDlcFcCvilr2K1sbYID1A3Db%2F%2B%2FCK5mcR1%2BWUNIjvF

The body is:

```
{ "location": { "lat":12.9219, "lng": 77.6193 }, "radius": "5000", "poiType": "bank", "countryCode": "in", "language": "en", "pageIndex": 1, "pageSize": 1, "politicalView":"in" }
```

I find a bank near the longitude and latitude on the map. However, the request cannot find the bank successfully.

Post request result:

```
{ "returnCode": "010010", "totalCount": 0, "returnDesc": "INVALID_REQUEST" }
```

Error code 010010 indicates incorrect parameter. However, I do not know what is incorrect. 
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Huawei LocationType](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/hms-site-locationType), you should enter BANK instead of bank. Enter BANK to try again.